# missing destination name u.shake_hands_id in *[]*model.ModelName

Tags: postgresql, go

I am getting this error when I am trying to  `tx.Select` from database some data.

> missing destination name u.shake_hands_id in *[]*model.ModelName

My Query is something like this:

```sql
SELECT u.shake_hands_id as "u.shake_hands_id",u.model_id as "u.model_id" 
FROM enquiry_interest u 
WHERE u.shake_hands_id=$1
```

my struct is like

```golang
type ShakesHandsModels struct {
    ShakeHandsId uuid.UUID `db:"shake_hands_id"`
    ModelId      string    `db:"model_id"`
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); It looks like you are using something in addition to the standard library (e.g. [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx)?) but don't provide any details of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query:

```
SELECT u.shake_hands_id as "u.shake_hands_id",u.model_id as "u.model_id" 
...
```

doesn't produce columns named `shake_hands_id` or `model_id` like your `struct` specifies. The double quotes around the aliases tell PostgreSQL to name the aliases `u.shake_hands_id` and `u.model_id` (i.e. the `.` are part of the alias names rather than acting as delimiters). You don't need the aliases at all, this:

```
SELECT u.shake_hands_id, u.model_id 
FROM enquiry_interest u 
WHERE u.shake_hands_id = $1
```

would be fine as would:

```
SELECT shake_hands_id, model_id 
FROM enquiry_interest
WHERE shake_hands_id = $1
```

If you must use the aliases for some reason, then don't bother with the quotes:

```
SELECT u.shake_hands_id as shake_hands_id, u.model_id as model_id
FROM enquiry_interest u 
WHERE u.shake_hands_id = $1
```

or make sure you only quote the right things:

```
SELECT u.shake_hands_id as "shake_hands_id", u.model_id as "model_id"
FROM enquiry_interest u 
WHERE u.shake_hands_id = $1
```

But really, don't use the quotes at all unless you really need them.